# Resize an image and save with imagejpeg()

Tags: php, resize

iam trying to resize an imageto a thumbnail with php! I get no errors but it won't save the thumbnail on my server. The code is:

```
#Resize image
function resize($input_dir, $cur_file, $newwidth, $output_dir)
{
    $filename = $input_dir.'/'.$cur_file;
    $format='';
    if(preg_match("/.jpg/i", $filename))
    {
        $format = 'image/jpeg';
    }
    if (preg_match("/.gif/i", $filename))
    {
        $format = 'image/gif';
    }
    if(preg_match("/.png/i", $filename))
    {
        $format = 'image/png';
    }
    if($format!='')
    {
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $newheight=$height*$newwidth/$width;
        switch($format)
        {
            case 'image/jpeg':
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
            break;
            case 'image/gif';
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
            break;
            case 'image/png':
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
            break;
        }
        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
        imagealphablending($thumb, false);
        imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($thumb, 'thumb_'.$cur_file);
    }
}
```

My function looks like:

```
resize(plugins_url().'/MyImagePlugin/img', 'testimg.jpg', "200");
```

The Image is in the Folder "img" in my Plugin Dic. The wired thing is ,that i don't get any erros?! CHMOD is 777 for img-folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using any path when you save the image in the line:

```
imagejpeg($thumb, 'thumb_'.$cur_file);
```

`$cur_file` is set to testing.jpg.

You should add the path to the filename or it will be attempoting to create it in whatever the current directory is.

Changes are something like :

```
function resize($input_dir, $cur_file, $newwidth, $output_dir = "" )
{
   if($output_dir == "") $output_dir = $input_dir;

   .....

      imagejpeg($thumb, $output_dir.'/thumb_'.$cur_file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I allready tried this. with `imagejpeg($thumb, $input_dir.'/thumb_'.$cur_file);` I get an error then: `Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open '...' for writing: No such file or directory` But I use the path from $input_dir and this path is 100% correct!

Comment: I don't quite see how your function / the way it is called is using the $input_dir

Comment: `$filename = $input_dir.'/'.$cur_file;` Both is stored in $filename.

Comment: yes - but the function imagejpeg which creates the file is not using $filename !

Comment: Well its using it. $filename -> $source -> $thumb. Anyway, got it to work. The problem was the path. I cant use "http://..." or relative paths. With my code above it was allways stored in /home/www/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not your way of doing but iam sure it can help you.

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']))
 {
  $saveto = "dirname/file.jpg";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
  $typeok = TRUE;
  switch($_FILES['image']['type'])
  {
  case "image/gif": $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;
  case "image/jpeg": // Both regular and progressive jpegs
  case "image/pjpeg": $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;
  case "image/png": $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;
  default: $typeok = FALSE; break;
  }
  if ($typeok)
  {
  list($w, $h) = getimagesize($saveto);
  $max = 500; 
  \\ you can change this to desired product for height and width.
  $tw = $w;
  $th = $h;
  if ($w > $h && $max < $w)
  {      
  $th = $max / $w * $h;
  $tw = $max;
  }
  elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)      
  {
  $tw = $max / $h * $w;
  $th = $max;
  }
  elseif ($max < $w)
  {
  $tw = $th = $max;
  }
  $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);      
  imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);
  imageconvolution($tmp, array( // Sharpen image
  array(-1, -1, -1),
  array(-1, 16, -1),
  array(-1, -1, -1)
  ), 8, 0);
  imagejpeg($tmp, $saveto);
  imagedestroy($tmp);
  imagedestroy($src);
  }
  }
```